# Everything seems to be an Aggregate Root

Tags: domain-driven-design

I want to model menus composition in a Restaurant. I've created a very small Bounded Context around just 3 concepts: `Menu`, `Category`, `Product`.

**Menus** are composed of different **Products** and every product in each menu is placed under a certain **Category** (a category is for example, "entrants", "1st course", "2nd course", "dessert"…).

The problem is that everything seems like an *Entity* to me.

For example, when a Menu is deleted, no Products or Categories are deleted. The same happens when the other 3 concepts.

Regarding the UI, Menus will be consumed like a hierarchy:

```
Menu1
    Category1
        Product1
        Product2
    Category2
        Product3
        Product4
```

I'm wondering how to model this. Should I make them 3 Aggregates? Then, how should a compose a Menu in order to be consumed like the hierarchy above?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like the perfect CRUD subdomain to me. As much as I advocate the use of DDD for complex domains, when there's a simple data-oriented hierarchy with very little domain logic and a probably low collaborative/concurrent factor like this, you may be better off building a very simple, RAD-style CRUD application or even consider buying it off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to make too much effort putting everything into DDD instead of making focus of the simplicity about this domain by just looking into the "real world. Please let me first go with an plain OO approach and just then let's talk about how to see it with DDD.
So you wanna have Menus so restaurant customers can look at them and choose whatever they want to eat. Let's suppose at the moment there will be just 1 menu for lunch, dinner, every weekday.
The restaurant manager should be able to create this Menu and change it whenever he wants to. 
This is our first use case

```
menu = new Menu("monday lunch", starters, mainEntrees, desserts, drinks);
```

where each of those parameters are lists of value objects (at first sight).
Just take a look at the real world, a menu is a description of the food you can get in a restaurant, those descriptions are inmutable objects (value objects) so so far we do not need anything else.
At this moment we have only one aggregate root that is Menu. It has global identity and groups a cluster of objects and has invariant. What class would I use to model an entree, dessert? String... an instance of String is enough so far.
What about the menu? We could have many Menus, one for monday, one for tuesday, one for friday night and so on, each having its own global identity so we have for sure the MenuRepository.
What about if the restaurant manager wants to add a new dessert?

```
menu = menuRepository.get(menuId);
menu.add(aDessert);
```

is enough. 
So far we have one Menu aggregate root and its repository. 
I think this is what you asked.

However, I think you missed the price. Each line on the menu would have prices, and two same desserts on different menus may have different prices if its lunch or dinner, so a more realistic approach seems to be:

```
menu = new Menu("monday lunch", starters, mainEntrees, desserts, drinks);
```

where starters, mainEntrees, desserts, drinks are a collection of type MenuLine.
Now what happens if the customer tells the waiter to bring him something to eat? a new order needs to be created to keep progress of what the customer asks in order to create an invoice later.
this order needs to know what food the customer asks, I mean what menu item the customer orders. So far we are using value objects to model the desserts, drinks, etc. Right now we should give some form or identifier to those options the customer can choose in order for us to have some unique identifier to use in order contexts such as orders. This is where we determine we need another Aggregate Root (the one you called Product). I would rather call it Food or something like that.
So when the restaurant manager decides to let the restaurant offer a new food the system would be

```
food = new Food("sushi");
foodRepository.add(food);
```

and then we the manager wants to add sushi to the menu of monday night

```
food = foodRepository.getBy(foodId);
menu = menuRepository.findByCriteria(mondayNight)
menu.addAt(food, tenDollars);
```

and what Menu does is

```
addAt(food, tenDollars) {
mainEntrees.add(new MenuItem(food.id, food.description, tenDollars)
}
```

we do not want the Menu to hold a reference to the Food aggregate root because of what vaughn vernon said in its book.

well hope it is helpfull. You do not need the concept of Category at all:

```
Menu {
List starters;
List entrees;
List desserts;
List drinks;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 5):

If you have a menu as an aggregate root with your current arrangement, then what would happen if you wanted to re-use the same product on a different menu? From outside the aggregate root, you wouldn't be able to hold a reference to it.

Instead I think that having Menu and Product (ask the Chef what he would call a food or menu item!) as aggregate roots are fine, as they both exist and have their own identity (you may have different menus over time, a menu may consist of food items that have been used on other menus).

Having the Category as a value object may be more fitting (again, maybe a Chef would call this a Course?) - how many Categories do you have (I believe these courses are probably fixed)? Does a category have its own life-cycle and identity? An enumerable on each product could fit this requirement well.

You also mention about deleting... that sounds like a technical infrastructure term. There are two issues with this:

1. If you did the above and split in to two aggregate roots (Menus and Products) how would you handle a delete of a Product when a Menu is referencing it? This becomes a transaction across two aggregate roots, which are hard to implement (one of the main ideas of DDD is defining transactional boundaries and enforcement of invariant via aggregates - any external operation on an aggregate root from the outside should leave it in a consistent state).
2. Think about what the chef or restaurant manager would do - would they delete a menu, or would they instead archive it or make it no longer available for selection?

One resource that will help solidify the above is Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon - http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

In terms of code, a psuedo mockup in C# would be below:

```
public Object HandleGetMenuCommand(
    string menuName,
    IMenuRepository menuRepository,
    ProductRepository productRepostiory)
{
    Menu menu = menuRepository.Get(new MenuId(menuName));
    List<ProductIds> productsInMenu = menu.Products;
    List<Products> products = productRepostiory.GetMany(productsInMenu);
    List<string> categories = ... // get a list of unique categories from products

    // now assemble products by category...
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
            var productsInCategory in products.Find(x => x.Category == category);
            foreach(var product in productsInCategory)
            {
                // add this to a list...
            }
    }

    var clientData = new {
        name = menu.Name,
        // add in the products that were assembled by category above
    }

    return clientData;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at the code trying to understand: it seems this method is inside a Service ("MenuService") because it performs operations with 2 repositories. If I understand you well, this method "inflates" an entity with everything the UI will need (a Menu entity base on the model, but specially designed to meet the requirements of the UI). Is this what you tried to mean or am I missing something? :) Thanks!

Comment: This would be at the application layer, which the UI would call. This is not a service inside the domain... but if it got significantly complex (and long) the business logic should be re-factored into a domain service, that the application service would make use of. Remember the application service job is to orchestrate all of moving parts required (in this case repositories) for the domain logic to run

Comment: OK! But I still see blurry lines with the Category. Yes, I think "Course" is a much better name for it :) Should it be a Value-Object?

Comment: A value object is something that doesnt have a distinct identity, like two courses named Desert... they are one in the same, you wouldn't have two separate entities called Desert (where as you could have two Human beings with the same name, for most domains those would be entities)... check out the Effective Aggregate Design link on my answer it will help clarify.

Comment: The article you linked is awesome. Useful and clarifying, as your answer and comments. Thanks a lot, I think I'm making great progress.