# Modelling contact details for a person / customer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, software-design

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way in managing contact details for an individual. Forget the SQL side of things for a moment, I am intrigued in how one would perhaps attempt to drive this via a DDD approach.

I was fooling around with some code in an effort to get comfortable with DDD as a whole and came up with the following which seems awful.

Firstly, I have an object called Person (simplified for the purpose of this post) where I envision methods to add and essentially manage different methods of communicating an individual.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.ContactDetails = new List<ContactDetails>();
    }

    public void AssociateContactDetails(ContactDetails contactDetails)
    {
        var existingContactDetails = this.ContactDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactType == contactDetails.ContactType);

        if (existingContactDetails != null)
        {
            this.ContactDetails.Remove(existingContactDetails);
        }

        this.ContactDetails.Add(contactDetails);
    }

    public IList<ContactDetails> ContactDetails { get; private set; }
}
```

Two approaches spring to mind. One where I have a fairly simple object like the one below which is quite generic (using the term loosely).

```
public enum ContactType
{
    Email, Telephone, Mobile, Post
}   

public class ContactDetails
{
    private readonly ContactType contactType;
    private readonly string value;

    public ContactDetails(ContactType contactType, string value)
    {
        this.contactType = contactType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ContactType ContactType
    {
        get { return this.contactType; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

But then I put myself into a corner with this approach as although it works well for trivial items such as email and telephone, when it comes to something like postal a string doesn't quite cut it. Therefore, after this I am heading towards the approach of having each mechanism of communication to represented by its own type, i.e.:

```
public class Post
{
    public Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Mobile
{
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}

public class Telephone
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    public string TelephoneNo { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Each type can then represented as a collection or single instance in the Person class? Seems long winded however is perhaps more readable and maintainable.

The question I guess is if there is a more elegant way in implementing such a feature and whether someone can point me in the direction of a good example similar to this. I imagine this is a common thing / problem to overcome.

Cheers, DS.

Comment: Not sure what value you get for having a different class for each type of contact info, just make the properties on your main `ContactInfo` class, you could make `Address` its own class if you want to re use it.

Comment: Yeah, I have an Address object which is a value type. However, just looking at how it would be modeled. For example, the Contact object I have I can use generics where T can be anything if that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know for sure what are the contact methods "email, "phone" and "address", so having identified those what we have to do first is to model those concepts taking into account what they really are. Let's take "email" as example and see what it really is in order to model it properly. It is a value object (an immutable object) that once created it will never change just as an integer number is an immutable object as well. The difference is that for modelling an integer number we can use the int type provided by any programming language, but the question is what class do we use for modelling en Email? Most of people would use a String instance to model an Email, but is this OK? In order to answer it let's see what is the protocol (the set of messages) a String object knows to response: "charAt(anIndex), replace(aString, anotherString), etc... ". Imagine that if we model an email by using a String class we could ask the email "replace(aString, anotherString)". That sounds weird, that message should not be part of the behavior an email should expose to other objects. Also so so important we said an email is immutable to it cannot expose behavior that at the end change it state. So it makes visible that we need to create a whole new abstraction to model an email and what is it? The Email class finally comes in!!! I know you suggested it but I just wanted to let you see why we need an Email class created.
First of all this is DDD (object oriented) so FORGET avoid setters and getters. In the email class you created you expose a setter method meaning that you can change the email and it contradicts with the nature of what an email is (immutable). An email is immutable from the momento it is created:

```
Email.fromString("monicalewinsky@gmail.com");
```

that is the same as doing

```
new Email("monicalewinsky@gmail.com");
```

The fromString method is a factory method that adds semantic to our domain model. This is very common in smalltalk instead of calling the constructor directly. Are we done??? Not at all. An email instance should be created as long as it is valid so the email class should assert the string from which is created is valid:

```
Email(String anEmailStringRepresentation) {
    assertIsValid(anEmailStringRepresentation);
}
```

assert is valid should verify it is actually an email string representation. This is that is has only one @ character, its local part is valid and then its domain part is valid. You can check the wikipedia for email address to understand better how it is composed.
Remember always that programming is a learning process, as long as we understand a domain better and better we reflect that domain in the code and it always must be consistent with the real world! Our Email class should look like more or less like:

```
class Email {

    String value;

    Email(aString) {
        value = aString;
 }

 public String getLocalPart()

 public String getDomainPart()

 public String asString()

 public boolean equals(anObject)

 public static Email fromString(aString)
}
```

That's it. It happens the same with PhoneNumber. It is also an inmmutable object and you should create a class with its own protocol. Remember never use set/get as you showed up if we are doing DDD. I don't think you need two value objects Telephone and Mobile since those are polymorphic objects and you could model a mobile phone number or a home phone number with the TelephoneNumber abstraction. It's like modelling a credit card. At the end you will end up and understand that the class CreditCard is enough and a better design than having several class such as Visa, MasterCard, and so on.
Let's skip the Address class and let's go back to your problem now.
So far we have identified and created properly all the value objects we need. Now we need to create an abstraction for representing an email, phonenumber, address as contact methods and if we keep loyal to the domain language we could say:

```
ContactMethod.for(Email.fromString("monica@gmail.com"));
```

or

```
ContactMethod.for(PhoneNumber("34234234234"));
```

etc

so our ContactMethod would look like:

```
class ContactMethod {

 static EMAIL = 1;
 static PHONE_TYPE = 2;
 static ADDRESS_TYPE = 3;

 String type;

 String value;

 ContactMethod(int aType, String aValue) {
     type = aType;
     value = aValue;
 }

 String getType()

 String getValue()

 public static ContactMethod at(Email anEmail) {
     return new ContactMethod(EMAIL, anEmail.asString());
 }

 public static ContactMethod at(PhoneNumber aPhoneNumber) {
     return new ContactMethod(PHONE_TYPE, aPhoneNumber.asString());
 }

 public static ContactMethod at(Address anAddress) {
     return new ContactMethod(ADDRESS_TYPE, anAddress.asString());
 }
}
```

See that ContactMethod is also an immutable class, actually a rule of thumb is that an Aggregate root should have ideally only an aggregation of value objects. 
This is finally how your Person class would look like:

```
class Person {

    List<ContactMethod> contactMethods;

    contactedAt(Email anEmail) {
        contactMethods.add(ContactMethod.at(anEmail));
    }

    contactedAt(PhoneNumber aPhoneNumber) {
        contactMethods.add(ContactMethod.at(aPhoneNumber));
    }

    contactedAt(Address anAddress) {
        contactMethods.add(ContactMethod.at(anAddress));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a fantastic explanation great detail and tbh I agree with you on most points. Although the passing of type on Contact method  object seems a little confusing and probably isn't self explanatory :)

Comment: you are correct, contact types can be better modelled as enums inside the boundary of ContactMethod

Answer (score 0):

On my journey of learning DDD sometimes I see patterns instead of problems... an interesting example [Everything seems to be an Aggregate Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722509/everything-seems-to-be-an-aggregate-root) is another answer I had provided regarding a menu, which had different categories such as starter, main, desert etc.

I had modeled this implicitly as a category string. After i posted there was a second answer where someone suggested modeling these as explicit lists of:

```
Menu {
List<Food> starters;
List<Food> entrees;
List<Food> desserts;
List<Food> drinks;
}
```

In this way, the entire concept of the category for a food was removed, this was enlightening for me and saw a different way of modeling and in this case reducing complexity.

My view is to try and model the code so that if I sat down with the business expert (who is not a developer) and showed them the use case code from a high level `person.SetMobileNumber("078321411", Countries.UK)` they would be able to understand it:

```
public void HandleUpdateMobileCommand(UpdateMobileNumber command)
{
    // repositories, services etc are provided in this handler class constructor
    var user = this.UserRepository.GetById(command.UserId);
    user.SetMobile(command.number, command.country);
    this.UserRepository.Save(user);

    // send an SMS, this would get the number from user.Mobile
    this.SmsService.SendThankYouMessage(user);  
}
```

Or even better, you could have a `MobileUpdated` event get fired when you update the user mobile, to which some code somewhere else (which is an expert on sending SMS messages, and nothing else) is listening to these events - for me this is the real power of DDD of breaking down code in to expert systems.

So in summary, I think your second suggestion of explicitly modeling with `Post`, `Mobile`, `Landline` and `Email` makes most sense.

I wouldn't say this a DDD domain or not as there isn't enough information on any complex logic (or multi-user race conditions) that you require, just to mention don't forget that you may be better writing a CRUD app if that makes more sense in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There's this central idea in DDD that domain modelling must take shape through discussion with domain experts. If you're making up these class names out of thin air, chances are they won't exactly match your real domain. Trivial ones such as Email or Telephone should be correct, but maybe for others you want feedback from an expert first.

Generally speaking, it's a good idea indeed to favor semantically rich modelling with dedicated value objects over primitive types. In C# it comes at a cost though since the amount of boilerplate code needed is huge (unlike F# for instance). This is why I usually prefer to do it only when the type has more than a single property or when there are specific construction rules or invariants to it.

Answer (score 0):

One good thing you can do is model your types as immutable `Value Objects`.  So something like:

```
public class Telephone
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    public string TelephoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

Might become:

```
public class TelephoneNumber
{
    private string areaCode;
    private string subscriberNumber;

    private TelephoneNumber()
    {
    }

    public TelephoneNumber(string areaCode, string subscriberNumber)
    {
        this.AreaCode = areaCode;
        this.SubscriberNumber = subscriberNumber;
    }

    public string AreaCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.areaCode;
        }

        private set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("AreaCode");
            }

            if ((value.Length <= 0) || (value.Length > 5))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("AreaCode");
            }

            this.areaCode = value;
        }
    }

    // Etc.
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, this is what I had in mind. When you come to think of it, when someone changes their number they are not making a modification to it, it is a brand new number being assigned just like if someone was to move house. This is where my DDD makes its appearance, thus not just just a CRUD app.

Comment: I'd missed something in my code example, I've added a private modifier to the setter, so it cannot be changed after construction.